# Variable changing value when used as a parameter

Tags: c#

My method takes a SearchCriteria parameter, then it passes this one parameter to 2 methods.  In GetFoo1, the criteria object is modified before being passed to another method which queries a database.

My expectation is, that the criteria object should be unchanged within the scope of this method.  That is, the exact same object is passed to GetFoo1 and GetFoo2, since I'm not passing criteria by reference.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx

```
public virtual async Task<SnapshotObject> GetSnapshot(SearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        var snapshot = new SnapshotObject();

        snapshot.Foo1 = await GetFoo1(criteria);
        snapshot.Foo2 = await GetFoo2(criteria);

        return snapshot;
    }
```

In this example, when I call GetFoo1, I'd expect criteria to be passed by value.  For some reason, when I pass the criteria object into GetFoo1, the modifications are persisted into when I pass it into GetFoo2, as if I passed by reference.

Comment: Maybe you want to 'clone' the instance of the class.

Comment: Jon Skeet have a very good article about this. See [this article](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because `SearchCriteria` is a class. So even though it's being passed by value, the value being passed is a reference to that object.

What that means is any changes to the object itself will be seen from the caller and other people accessing the same object:

```
var list = new List<string>();
MyMethod(list);
if(list.Count == 0)   // this one will be false because list now have 1 item
    ....

void MyMethod(List<string> list)
{
    list.Add("hey!");
}
```

However, they are not able to replace the entire object:

```
var list = new List<string>();
MyMethod(list);
if(list.Count == 0)   // this one will be true
    ....

void MyMethod(List<string> list)
{
    list = new List<string>() { "hey!" }; // does not affect the caller.
}
```

If you passed that argument by reference second example would change the caller to point to that newly created `List<string>` instead with 1 item in it.

It's explaining in the article you linked to in "Passing Reference Types by Value" part:

> The following example demonstrates passing a reference-type parameter, `arr`, by value, to a method, `Change`. **Because the parameter is a reference to `arr`, it is possible to change the values of the array elements.** However, the attempt to reassign the parameter to a different memory location only works inside the method and does not affect the original variable, `arr`.